# Javascript API for complex CSS attributes

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm writing some javascript code that heavily manages the DOM and I'd like to be confident that my code is efficient.

I'm wondering whether there is a native, browser-provided API allowing javascript to manage complex css attributes? I am interested in performance so I would like to use tools that are as native as possible.

If I open the console on any webpage I can type and witness the following:

```
>>> window.document.body.style.transform = 'translate(0, 0)';
"translate(0, 0)"
>>> window.document.body.style.transform
"translate(0px, 0px)"
```

Obviously the `style.transform` property is not a simple property for it is reformatting `0` as `0px`. But the value of the `style.transform` property is a simple string!

Is there any API for managing complex css attributes such as `transform`?

Something like the following?

```
>>> var elem = document.getElementById('some-id');
>>> elem.style.niceTransform.translate
null
>>> elem.style.niceTransform.rotate
null
>>> elem.style.niceTransform.scale
null
>>> elem.style.niceTransform.translate = 'transform(10, 20, 30)';
>>> elem.style.niceTransform.translate
CSSTransformTranslate { x: 10, y: 20, z: 30 }
>>> elem.style.niceTransform.translate.y += 20;
>>> elem.style.niceTransform.translate
CSSTransformTranslate { x: 10, y: 40, z: 30 }
```

Obviously I have invented the `niceTransform` property and `CSSTransformTranslate` class. Do browsers provide javascript with an api for managing complex css properties? If so, could I get a link to such documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by `complex css properties`? According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units) "The format of a length value (denoted by <length> in this specification) is a <number> (with or without a decimal point) immediately followed by a unit identifier (e.g., px, em, etc.). *After a zero length, the unit identifier is optional*."

Comment: [This css documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#css) may be helpful, best of luck!

Comment: For example `font-style` is not a complex property. The `font-style` property has no sub-properties; it is simply an inline string such as `"serif"` or "`sans-serif"`. But the `transform` property is complex - it has `scale`, `translate`, and `rotate` properties, and each of those components has further sub-properties. (e.g. `transform` has `x`, `y`, and `z` properties).

Comment: You're looking for the [CSSOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/).

Comment: I'm not sure that CSSOM link has anything to say about manipulating complex css attributes! If it does, or it doesn't because such a thing doesn't exist, please post an answer :)

Comment: To stack CSS transforms, you will have to calculate/generate a CSS transformation matrix, [a task that should not be taken very lightly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Matrix_math_for_the_web#What_is_a_transformation_matrix). There is hitherto no JS API to do that, and the matrix generation is done by the rendering engine instead. Therefore, instead of reinventing the wheel, I suggest you take a look at transform-centric JS plugins such as Velocity.js, which conveniently allows stacking of CSS transforms ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the style properties are all strings; they only accept a string, so if you wanted an API like that you would have to create it yourself, keep track of the states of all properties, and then set the transform string when a change is made.

That said, there is something *kind of* similar in [CSSMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSMatrix). CSSMatrix itself has been deprecated, and it has vendor prefixed versions, and there is a newer DOMMatrix...it's a bit of a mess. I do see that there is at least one [polyfill](https://github.com/arian/CSSMatrix) but I've never used it so try it at your own risk.

But the nice thing about the matrix is that in JS you can *get* the current transform as a Matrix, *apply* a skew/rotate/translate to that Matrix, and then *set* the transform property to your updated Matrix. That does some of what you are looking for, I think; you would just need to decide if implementing it is worth it based on the browser support you need.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 supports transforms natively https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp
You can just add/modify the necessary rule in the stylesheet through javascript.

Since you're manipulating the DOM heavily, i would also recommend using JQuery, since it is universally known and well optimized.

Comment: I'm looking for a javascript API, not css!

Comment: What i'm saying is to use javascript to set the CSS. Is there any reason you want a javascript api over css/html? You should want to minimize the javascript to cut down on load times, since the javascript libraries will be editing the CSS anyway.

Comment: Setting transforms vs stacking transforms are very different things, I think OP is asking for the latter. The former is quite straightforward, the latter not so.

Comment: I'm looking to manage the `transform` property in an object-oriented way. Currently I'm not aware of any way to access a `transform.translate.x` property. If I want to change an element's `x` position, I need to set the entire `transform` property. I essentially asked my question to determine if I can avoid setting the entire `transform` property, and drill straight down the the `transform.translate.x` property.